# no themes or editor under appearance menu

Tags: admin-menu

I inherited a site which does not have all of the menu items under the appearance menu in the toolbar. Specifically themes (trying to upload a new theme my client purchased) and editor.

I have:

- changed disallow to false in the wp-config.php file
- searched for any action that removed the theme (remove_editor type of language) or editor menu in the functions.php file for the theme, and other themes installed - couldn't find anything.
- completely deleted the theme via ftp (as I don't have that access to the WP dashboard) and still didn't have a full appearance menu
- added themes node $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $themes); in the admin-toolbar.php in the mu-plugins folder and removed the $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'themes' ); in same file.
- tried the same as above in the admin-menu file

Help?! What am I missing and where could it be written to not show those nodes in the appearance toolbar? I'm frustrated.

Also - thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, perhaps it's a permissions or admin role? I didn't see that in the functions file, either.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure that your user is an 'admin' type. Then I would reinstall WP core files (via the update, if that is available; otherwise you will have to do a selective file transfer so as to not to overwrite your settings).

I would also rename the 'plugins' folder to 'xxplugins' temporarily, to ensure that a plugin is not involved.

And I seem to recall that if you rename the 'themes' folder, WP will default to an internal theme; not sure on that. You could also transfer the default (the 'twenty...' themes) themes via FTP, overwriting existing themes.

Also, check for a standard wp-config file, looking for any changes.